# android 13 multi touch issue

Tags: android, multi-touch

My app a synthesizer app with an on-screen keyboard was working fine in my old tablet.

Now I am testing it on my new tablet with android 13 and when I press three piano keys at the same time Logcat displays that my activity has captured a "FingersGesture gesture" event that waits for cancel motion.

This ruins the multi touch of my application. So any hints are appreciated what is it and how to disable this gesture event.